# Rails - required asset files, @import and global scope variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I have a bunch of separate files where I hold my variables which are used project-wide. Since variables wont persist through different scss files throughtout the project I have to import them right after the beggining of my application.css.scss file:

```
@import "filename.css.scss"
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

Now everything that I import via @import gets imported right away without any problem. Everything that I try to import via the sprockets just gets ignored; so if I import each and every SCSS file by hand using @import directive, it all gets imported nicely - which means that files can be accessed by an app. Any idea what can be wrong?

I am using rails v 3.2.6, sprockets 2.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time browsing web and reading sprockets docs I found out the following:

Sprockets parse only the beginning of file (until it reaches the end of first comment block), so:

```
@import "filename.css.scss"
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
```

This will import filename.css.scss but will ignore the ***= require jquery-ui** directive.

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui
 */
@import "filename.css.scss"
```

This will work just fine and load jquery-ui and then import filename.css.scss.

Hope this will help someone in the future.